# Destructor throwing an exception

Tags: c++, exception

I'm reading Scott Meyerses `C++` and now I'm at the destructor throwing exceptions section. Here is what is he said:

> When the vector `v` is destroyed, it is responsible for destroying all
>   the `Widget`s it contains. Suppose `v` has ten `Widget`s in it, and during
>   destruction of the first one, an exception is thrown. **The other nine**
>   `Widget`s **still have to be destroyed (otherwise any resources they hold**
>   **would be leaked)**, **so v should invoke their destructors**. **But suppose**
>   **that during those calls, a second Widget destructor throws an**
>   **exception.** Now there are two simultaneously active exceptions

So, as far as I undesrstood it, if the first element of a vector throws an exception it doesn't mean the program to be terminated right after that. The implementation tries to destroy the other objects in the vector instead. Let me provide an example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct A
{
    ~A(){ std::cout << "destruction" << std::endl; throw std::exception(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a[] = {A(), A(), A(), A(), A(), A()};
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.assign(a, a+6);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4a0e12419c1a478)**

The program was terminated right after the first exception throwing. Where is the promised the second exception throwing?

Comment: I don't have the book handy at the moment, but from what I recall, it's a hypothetical. It explains why the language doesn't actually work this way - because if it tried to work this way, it would lead to absurd outcomes. It also explains why it's a really bad idea to ever throw from a destructor.

Comment: Aside from being a bad idea, you never catch the first exception so the program `terminate`s before it can even begin to destroy the other objects.

Comment: @user657267 ... and indeed, it's not trivial to catch it, because it's in a destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a destructor invoked by a standard library component exits via an exception, the behavior is undefined. [res.on.functions]/p2, emphasis mine:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - [...]
> - if any replacement function or handler function or **destructor operation** exits via an exception, unless specifically allowed in the
>     applicable *Required behavior:* paragraph.
> - [...]

Comment: But what about any other destrctors exit via exeption?

Comment: @DmitryBundin Then usual rules apply. Handlers are searched for. Stack is unwound. And if a destructor invoked by stack unwinding exits via an exception, then `std::terminate` is called, etc.

Comment: So, it's doesn't matter whether we throw an exception from the destructor or any other place in out program. The result's going to be the same. I've found that throwing exception exactly in the destructor is dangerous. If the usual rules apply, why the destructor throwing exception is a special case?

Comment: @DmitryBundin Because you rely on destructors to perform clean up during stack unwinding, and that must not fail (or `std::terminate` will be called).

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to Item 8 "Prevent exceptions from leaving destructors". Your quote of the text truncates it mid sentence:

> *Now there are two simultaneously active exceptions*, **and that's one too many for C++**. Depending on the precise conditions under which such pairs of simultaneously active exceptions arise, program execution either terminates or yields undefined behavior.

You indicate that you "undesrstood it, if the first element of a vector throws an exception it doesn't mean the program to be terminated right after that"

Well, it does if you don't catch it, because that's what uncaught exceptions do.

Alternatively, you catch it. By doing so, you have left the frame of execution that was doing the destruction, and so whatever *was* going on is no-longer going on.

```
// speculative "what if"

struct A { ~A() { raise std::exception(); } };

void f() {
   A a, b;
} // b and a go out of scope, the first one throws

int main() {
    try {
        f();
    } catch (...) {
        // << program is now here.
    }
}
```

There is no mechanism to "resume" the termination code for `f()`, an exception occurred, that code path is done, so if it was `a` that destructed, `b` will never destruct; or vice versa.

Ok, you were talking about a vector. So you perceive that, say, std::vector::clear is doing something like:

```
clear() {
    while (!empty()) {
        try {
            erase(back());
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            // something went wrong, lets ignore it
        }
        m_size--;
    }
}
```

Your understanding that "if an exception occurs, the implementation tries to destroy the other objects in the vector instead" is false. As Meyers says, the STL doesn't expect or encourage exceptions from destructors, so it doesn't try to handle them. I don't know where you got this understanding from, but it's inaccurate, sorry, and if the language *tried* to implement it, we'd be in a real mess because if something went wrong enough to generate an exception while trying to destroy an object, things would get really messy.